# Tz Conversion Pandas/Yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I've just made a fresh installation of Linux 18.04.6 LTS (Bionice Beaver) and can't get a python script to work. This script worked before the fresh installation and works on my Windows PC, but can't seen to work here. Here is the test code im running:

```
df = web.get_data_yahoo('^BVSP', progress=False,show_errors=False)
print(df)
```

The problem seems to be only with BVSP, which is the brazilian index (IBOVESPA), it works for other brazilian tickers, as "AALR3.SA" as an example, for american tickers, as "AAPL" as an example, and crypto, as "BTC-USD" as an example, but my script needs the ^BVSP data and I can't seem to make it work.

Here is the output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 104, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 201, in _download_one_threaded
    keepna, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 218, in _download_one
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 315, in history
    df.index = _pd.to_datetime(df.index.date).tz_localize(tz_exchange, ambiguous=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py", line 235, in tz_localize
    arr = self._data.tz_localize(tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 972, in tz_localize
    self.asi8, tz, ambiguous=ambiguous, nonexistent=nonexistent
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.pyx", line 319, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 1997-10-06 00:00:00
```

It seems like a timezone problem, I've tried formatting directly from yahoo data but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

See section ['pandas_datareader override'](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)).
And perhaps the syntax has changed.

Try this for me it works:

```
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

yf.pdr_override()

print(pdr.get_data_yahoo('^BVSP', progress=False,show_errors=False))
```

Or

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('^BVSP', progress=False,show_errors=False)

print(df)
```